# Prove that if $\forall \omega \in \Omega$, $X(\omega) \leq Y(\omega), P(X \leq Y) = 1$

Tags: probability, statistics

I have thought about this question for hours. It just did not make sense for me.

I think it is implied that X and Y are totally dependent. Both random variables are using the same "experiment". It means if $\omega_1$ happens, you will get X($\omega_1$) and Y($\omega_1$). We know that $\forall \omega \in \Omega$, $X(\omega) \leq Y(\omega)$. Therefore, $P(X \leq Y) = 1$

Am I wrong? Do you have any other explanation? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with dependence/independence. The notation $P(X\le Y)$ means
$$
P(\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)\leq Y(\omega)\})\;.
$$
By the assumption, this is $P(\Omega)=1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it does make sense. I almost forgot all the notations. Should have not skipped the lectures.

Comment: @mathworkswizard: thanks. You are welcome:-)